# Using relative url in QT stylesheet

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I'm working with a qt project and want to set all the image files relative but I can't access the images using the usual parent url reference.

```
image:url('../sources/status/status.png');
```

I can however load the image using the image's absolute path.

Comment: The path is relative to your source code or the location of the executable?

Comment: Are you using python or C++?

Comment: It is relative to both the source code and the location of executable.

Comment: I am using python.

Comment: If you are using python there is no executable.

Comment: Yeah, I got confused.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works, I think the error is generated by something else, you could share your complete project zipped through drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: qt-creator is not a valid tag if you use python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use the [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). The dependencies of your resources will be included with you executable file and then you don't have to share the folder tree.

You can use the resource url to set up the image in your QSS code.

Create resource with all your image, you can use the Qt Creator IDE to set up it easily. If you want you can add your own prefix to distinguish with the rest of the resources.

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0" prefix="/">
<qresource>
   <file>../sources/status/status.png</file>
   <file>../sources/status/example_1.png</file>
   <file>../sources/status/example_2.png</file>
   <file>../sources/status/example_3.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then if your prefix, its "/", then use this for your QSS:

```
image:url(':/../sources/status/status.png');
```

Comment: The OP asked for relative path not a qss tutorial, although i agree with you in most cases